# UART interrupt on ARM Cortex-M0 not triggering while utilizing FreeRTOS

Tags: stm32, uart, freertos, cortex-m

I am using an STM32F0 with the following std_periph_lib api functions to configure and execute a UART transmit from a FreeRTOS queue.

```
// Initialization
{
  USART_InitTypeDef usart_init;
  USART_StructInit(&usart_init);
  usart_init.USART_BaudRate = 9600;
  USART_Init(s_port[uart].base, &usart_init);

  USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE);
  USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_TXE, DISABLE);
  USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);

  NVIC_InitTypeDef init_struct = {
    .NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn,
    .NVIC_IRQChannelPriority = 0,
    .NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE,
  };
  NVIC_Init(&init_struct);
}
```

```
// Transmit
  // Write all passed data to queue
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (queue_send(&queue, &data[i], 0) != pdTRUE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE) == SET) {
    uint8_t tx_data = 0;
    // get first byte from queue to initiate transmission
    UBaseType_t cmpl = queue_receive(&queue, &tx_data, 0);
    if (cmpl == pdFALSE) { // No data left in queue
      USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_TXE, DISABLE);
      return status;
    }
    
    // Send first byte
    USART_SendData(USART1, tx_data);
    // Enable TX Interrupts to begin transmission
    USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_TXE, ENABLE);
  }
```

I have confirmed that the data is received from the queue, and that the USART_SendData and USART_ITConfig execute, but the isr:

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void) {
}
```

is never executed. Does anyone know what may be causing this?
I have read the FreeRTOS docs concerning ARM interrupt structure ([here](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html)) and have confirmed that my ISR is at a lower logical priority than configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY and higher than configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY.

Comment: What USART event is supposed to trigger interrupt?

Comment: USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_TXE, ENABLE) unmasks the periodic USART interrupt so that it should be triggered periodically

Comment: Put debugging breakpoint after USART_SendData(USART1, tx_data);, put a delay there (just enough so that the byte is shifted out), and check in the USART SR/ISR register if the TXE flag is set. Also, try the maximum priority for the interrupt, just to see if it behaves any differently. (Try these two things separately of course, so that you know what caused changed in behavior)